Visual Studio 2022 - Multiple Publish Profiles - Publishing a file using context menu
In VS 2022, Right-clicking any file in my project (html, js.. et) it gives me an option to "Publish" it. I also have multiple profiles in under Properties>PublishProfiles.
If I publish entire project, it's simple.. I select the appropriate profile from Publish interface, but if I right click on any file and choose "Publish", it never asks me where to publish to. It just publishes and the output appears to be meaningless.. can't tell where it goes:
06:21:34:192    Preparing to publish files...
06:21:52:442    Using ID '1ddd2b24-0de2-489e-a3a8-19da405253af' for connections to the remote server.
06:21:53:460    Using ID '38d44861-870c-4738-a1e7-72ce9b352155' for connections to the remote server.
06:21:54:622    Your file(s) have been successfully published.

Is there an option to set default profile? How do I tell where my file is being published to and why does it show 2 IDs in the output?
Thanks!
Dug through all the menu options. Do not see an option to set default profile. Do not see an option to choose profile when deploying a single file via right-click.

by default it will use the profile you chose last time.It will also jump to pubxml editor when you click publish. Also I am unable to select a single file when right clicking any single file.

@Amadeusz Kurusu For me, it does not open publish interface when publishing single file.. it immediately shows publishing details in command line. That's what made it so hard to figure out. But I did test it and can confirm that last selected profile is where single files end up going

No. It's not possible to set a "default" profile. It will always use the picked publish profile for the project (You change this by right-clicking the project and click "Publish...") when publishing specific files.

Just to clarify, I have 3 profiles available in the drop-down on the "Publish" screen when I right-click my project and select "Publish". That screen does not have a "save" feature. Are you suggesting that whatever I select in the drop-down ends up being the go-to profile if I then right-click on any file in my project and choose "Publish"? It does not take me back to the publish screen.. it immediately starts deploying the file without providing destination details (so cryptic!)

Yep. I agree it's very cryptic. But that is sadly how it works.

Thank you, Mikkel. I'll test this out and check back in.

@user26572149 no problem!
